# Can i use fsmonitor or watchr with electron js?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, typescript, angular, electron

I am trying to use `fsmonitor` or `watchr` with angular2 based electron app build getting failed

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

let fsmonitor = require('fsmonitor');
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './home.html'
})

export class AppComponent {
 names: string[];
  constructor() {
    this.names = [];
}
```

is there any alternative from angular2 to monitor file changes?

Comment: What exactly is it that fails for you?

Comment: require('fsmonitor) not found if i use in angular2 component